# Quartz job not started as expected when reset date in Linux

Tags: java

I'm testing the quartz jobs by resetting date in Linux. I have 3 jobs with cron expressions as below:

```
Job 1: 0 05 11 * * ?
Job 2: 0 0 0 * * ?
Job 3: 0 0 1 * * ?
```

With Job 1 when I reset date with command:

```
date +%T -s "11:05:00"
```

this job not always started, sometimes it not work.

With Job 2 and Job 3 when I reset date with command:

```
date +%T -s "00:00:00"
date +%T -s "00:01:00"
```

they never activated as I expected.

What should I do next? Please give me some advices or hints in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the meaning of your cron expression

cron is executed after the starting time

so first set the date also of the next day

```
Job 1: 0 05 11 * * ? - executes every day 11:05 AM
Job 2: 0 0 0 * * ? -executes every day 12:00 AM
Job 3: 0 0 1 * * ? - executes every day 1:00 AM
```

mean when you change the time make sure that change time before some seconds and let it execute it itself at the time of schedule.

you can check when the cron is get scheduled next time here http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: If cron 0 0 0 * * ? means executes every day 12:00 AM not 00:00? Then what cron expression to run at 00:00?

Comment: 00:00 A.M. is same as 12:00 A.M.and 00:00 P.M. is same as 12:00 P.M.

Answer (score 1):

If you reset the date to the exact time the jobs are supposed to start, Quartz may not wake up and check the time quickly enough.  Set the time to 1 minute before the scheduled time.